# Getting both YMIN and YMAX from ffmpeg's signalstats

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the following ffmpeg command to get YMIN/YMAX values from the signalstats filter.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mxf -vf "signalstats,metadata=print:key=lavfi.signalstats.YMIN:file=logfileMIN.txt", signalstats,metadata=print:key=lavfi.signalstats.YMAX:file=logfileMAX.txt" -an -f null -
```

This takes double the time than when getting a single Y value. Is there a more optimized way to do this? (and preferably also to a single logfile)
(btw, I can't use ffprobe)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the only way I could make this work is by printing all the signalstats values to the logfile. It's not ideal as you'd have to parse a lot of data but the important thing is that ffmpeg doesn't take twice the time to process.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mxf -vf "signalstats,metadata=print:file=logfile.txt" -an -f null -
```